# hide the background from overlapping svgs in react native

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I am trying to create shape of two circles overlapping on each other and i have done it successfully just overlapping part is showing background image instead of image which is set inside circles and quite new in react-native-svg area so please help me. Here is my code:

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../assets/images/20.png')} style={styles.background}>
    <Svg height={height} width="100%">
        <Defs>
            <ClipPath id="clip">
                <Circle cx="320" cy="230" r="250" />
                <Circle cx="80" cy="150" r="180" />
            </ClipPath>
        </Defs>
        <SvgImg
            href={require('../assets/images/18.jpg')}
            width={500}
            height={500}
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            clipPath="url(#clip)"
        />
    </Svg>
</ImageBackground>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        width: 'auto',
        height: '100%',
    },
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in ImageBackground

Because style needs to be defined for the internal image as well

try set imageStyle

```
 <ImageBackground
    imageStyle={{
      resizeMode: 'contain',//or try anohter style
      overflow: 'visible',
   }}
  >
```

Comment: try anohter style?

Comment: version  for what?

Comment: react-native-svg library version 10